# How does website display notifications after its page closed?

Tags: javascript, html

After visiting Facebook website and closing its page, weeks after I'm still getting browser notifications from Facebook about messages, posts, etc.

How is it implemented? Could a website install some scripts to be executed indefinitely regardless of having the website opened in a browser?

Comment: Sometimes sites implement functionality related to the notifications API - you likely saw a pop up asking if you were ok with this site showing notifications.  If you clicked 'Allow' (or yes) - the site would be able to display pop-up notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most of browsers are allowing what we called it Push notifications

For example if in Chrome Browser 
if you look at chrome://settings/content/notifications

You will find all websites allowed to send you notifications, it's kind of embedded scripts that will be stored in the browser website's cache

The notifications are simply an implementation of Observer design Pattern

Answer (score -1):

actually the website makes a socket connection with your browser so even if you close your browser you can get push notification!